# Weblogic subscriber multiple URL

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, subscriber

I am using two url ,but if one server associated with url is down than want to hit Another url ie.suppose here osb 1 is down than i want to go to osb2 but here i am getting error because osb1 is down

```
private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://osb1.dev.intial.com:8011" +"t3://osb2.dev.intial.com:8011");
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"637tu5");
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"ABCD@123");

        return new InitialContext(h);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit wrong about setting the PROVIDER_URL property. Your URLS should be set like that :

```
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://osb1.dev.intial.com:8011,osb2.dev.intial.com:8011");
```